# Session variable not altering view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got a simple endpoint that sets a session variable:

```
Session.Add("IsAwesome", true);
```

I have a helper class that let's me check that variable:

```
    public static bool IsAwesome()
        {
            var isAwesome = HttpContext.Current.Session["IsAwesome"];
            if (isAwesome == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return (bool)isAwesome;
        }
```

I call that method in a view:

```
@if(Helper.IsAwesome()) {
    <h1>You're awesome!</h1>
} else {
    <h1>You're not awesome.</h1>
}
```

When I hit the endpoint, the session variable is set, but the view doesn't update. I set breakpoints in the helper, and the code doesn't run unless I make another change to my .cshtml file. It's like it's getting cached.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you hitting the endpoint ? Is the view being reloaded/code being rerun after you set the session value

Comment: It's hit with an AJAX call, and on success they're redirected to another page. The view logic is in a layout so should render on every page.

Comment: `return (bool)isAwesome;` doesn't compile.

Comment: It's copied from my code that is running fine, aside from this weird caching issue...

Comment: @opticon You're casting a `string` to `bool` that cannot be ok.

Comment: Your code should work as long as you are redirecting to a new page after setting the session so the code will be executed on the next GET request for that page.

Comment: That was my thought, and it is redirecting, and the GET request is happening, but the code isn't running :/

Comment: What do you mean by _unless I make another change to my .cshtml file_ ?

Comment: Any other material change. If I go change some code/content, it seems like it recognizes the file has been changed and it's time to run the code again.

Comment: I tried in a fiddle (https://dotnetfiddle.net/5zQlk8) and your code sample worked properly. What's actually got wrong, is that your view page doesn't refreshed to show the message?